# Qlik Sense Extension getList('SelectionObject')

Tags: extension-methods, qliksense

I would like to get help solving a problem with this code:
I'm developing a Qlik sense Extension using JavaScript.
I Write the function `GetCurrSelect` , And I want it to run only when I call it from the paint function.
But every time the program needs to run the paint function, it first run the `GetCurrSelect` function and even several times.
I tried to add the condition `if(a===1)` But it did not help, the program accesses this function even without invoke it.

This is my code:

```
define(["jquery", "qlik", "text!./Network_Diagram.css","./d3.min"], function($ , qlik, cssContent) {'use strict';
    $("<style>").html(cssContent).appendTo("head");
    qlikG=qlik.currApp();
 function GetCurrSelect(a){
    if(a===1)
    {   
      try{
  
         qlikG.getList('SelectionObject',  function(reply){
         alert("here!");
           
            });
          }
          
          catch(err){
          currSelectionNum=0;
          }
          
          }
    }
     return {
       //....
        
        
        paint : function($element,layout) {
         GetCurrSelect(1);
         }
     //....
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `app.getList()` is not returning a list. It is *subscribing* to any changes to the list.

So the callback will be executed every time the list changes.

If you want to avoid that, you need to destroy the list object after getting the values first time.

Qlik Help: [destroySessionObject()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2019/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/AppAPI/destroySessionObject-method.htm)